# Excluding specific values from a range of cells

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I would like to remove #N/A values from being counted in my sparklines. #N/As are produces with `=NA()`.

My formula is `=SPARKLINE(D5:AN5, {"ymin", 0})`.

How do I exclude specific values from the "D5:AN5" range? I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering data:

`=SPARKLINE(FILTER(D5:J5,ISNA(D5:AN5)=false), {"ymin", 0})`